# Using a Collector on a primitive stream

Tags: java, java-8, primitive, boxing, java-stream

Is there in Java 8 any way to use [Stream::collect(Collector)](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-) on primitive streams?

Normally a `Stream<Integer>` as example has two methods for collecting:

- [`<R,A> R collect(Collector<? super T,A,R> collector)`](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-)
- [`<R> R collect(Supplier<R> supplier,
            BiConsumer<R,? super T> accumulator,
            BiConsumer<R,R> combiner)`](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.BiConsumer-java.util.function.BiConsumer-)

However `IntStream` only has one method for collecting:

- [`<R> R collect(Supplier<R> supplier,
            ObjIntConsumer<R> accumulator,
            BiConsumer<R,R> combiner)`](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#collect-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.ObjIntConsumer-java.util.function.BiConsumer-)

Now as example code I have the following:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    result = LongStream.range(1, maximum).boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> i, i -> (int)Iterators.longStream(new CollatzGenerator(i)).count()))
            .entrySet().stream()
            .max(Comparator.comparingLong(Map.Entry::getValue))
            .get().getKey();
}
```

As you can see I first box the primitives in order to be able to use a `Collectors.` method.

Is there any way I can use primitives and still have the same code with `Collectors.toMap`
?

Comment: Since the Map will contain objects anyway, what's there to gain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `Map` is a Generic interface there is no way to create a `Map` without boxing. However, it doesn’t make sense to collect items into a `Map` at all when all you want is to create another stream (with just two values wrapped in a `Map.Entry`). You can just create the `Map.Entry` instances without collecting the values:

```
LongStream.range(1, maximum)
  .mapToObj(i->new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(i, Iterators.longStream(new CollatzGenerator(i)).count()))
  .max(Comparator.comparingLong(Map.Entry::getValue))
  .get().getKey();
```

This still does auto-boxing but once you are at this point you can get rid of the `Map.Entry` too by creating an appropriate value holder class by yourself:

```
static final class TwoLongs {
    final long key, value;
    TwoLongs(long k, long v) { key=k; value=v; }
    public long getKey() { return key; }
    public long getValue() { return value; }
}
```

With this holder class you can process your data without boxing the `long`s:

```
LongStream.range(1, maximum)
  .mapToObj(i->new TwoLongs(i, Iterators.longStream(new CollatzGenerator(i)).count()))
  .max(Comparator.comparingLong(TwoLongs::getValue))
  .get().getKey();
```

Well, it is still some kind of boxing but creating one item (the `TwoLongs` instance) object instead of three (one `Map.Entry` and two `Long`s).

Comment: This is still more complicated than it has to be.

Comment: Do you mean, there's a simpler way in Java 8, or that there ought to be a simpler way, such as if Java were to provide tuples, or easier ways to generate finite streams?

Comment: @Stuart Marks: he was referring to the possibility to integrate the logic of the second value into the `Comparator` function. So there would be no need for mapping to a kind of *pair* inside the stream but the disadvantage would be that the `Comparator` would calculate the values more often than necessary. So for a trivial mapping it could simplify the code but for this use case it’s not recommended. I think he revoked his answer for that reason.

Answer (score 0):

```
long result = LongStream.range(0, 9)
        .mapToObj(i -> new long[]{i, i})
        .max(Comparator.comparingLong(pair -> pair[1]))
        .get()[0];
```